# How to cast an object to byte array in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my object `var loginParameters = ["Tander", "ali", "1", "WINDOWS", "2.0", "TOSHIBA-PC"]`

And I want to convert this object to byte array that will look like `byte[] objName`. But I couldn't find anything about this.

How can I succeed this?

Comment: Where is the object man....??

Comment: Sorry about notation. I am not skilled with js. I mean 'loginParamaters' object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var mainbytesArray = [];
for(var i = 0; i < loginParameters.length; i++){
    var bytes = [];
    for (var j = 0; j < loginParameters[i].length; ++j)       
        bytes.push(loginParameters[i].charCodeAt(j));
    mainbytesArray.push(bytes);
}
```

Comment: Is there a better way to do this?